# Why are my tomato leaves yellowing?

Tags: diseases, tomatoes

I'm in Toronto Canada and noticed no fruit set as well as many lower leaves turning yellow. Is this a nitrogen issue? I also noticed an abundance of pillbugs near my plot too, some even eating the lower leaves.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we have a photo of the whole plant

Comment: @RohitGupta added!